# Do I need to have same eBPF kernel config on both physical and virtual machine, in order to use eBPF on virtual machine?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, virtual-machine, ebpf

I want to run eBPF on virtual machine, suppose it's KVM

Do I need to have same kernel config on physical machine to run eBPF on KVM. In other words, do I need to  set CONFIG_BPF=y CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y on physical machine?

If I want to test this, is that I need to recompile a new kernel on physical machine, with changed kernel config? Thank you.

I searched something on kernel config, while didn't find related topic.

Answer (score 0):

No, you only need to change the kernel config of your guest kernel if that's where you intend to load the BPF programs.